# Regex BS4 output for part of ,<link>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, rss

I am parsing this RSS feed:

https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/12700550304290381537/6239785894655863043

I am using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/12700550304290381537/6239785894655863043"
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features='xml')
items = soup.findAll('entry')

news_items = []

for item in items:
  news_item = {}
  news_item['title'] = item.title.text
  news_item['link'] = item.link['href']
  news_item['published'] = item.published.text
  news_item['source'] = item.link
  news_items.append(news_item)

news_items[0]
```

I get the following output:

```
{'link': <link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&amp;sa=t&amp;url=https://duitslandinstituut.nl/artikel/38250/duitsland-lanceert-corona-tracing-app&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyGWFlODkwMWNhMWM0YmE4ODU6bmw6bmw6Tkw&amp;usg=AFQjCNHDFPconO3h8mpzJh92x4HrjPL2tQ"/>,
 'published': '2020-06-11T15:33:11Z',
 'source': <link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&amp;sa=t&amp;url=https://duitslandinstituut.nl/artikel/38250/duitsland-lanceert-corona-tracing-app&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyGWFlODkwMWNhMWM0YmE4ODU6bmw6bmw6Tkw&amp;usg=AFQjCNHDFPconO3h8mpzJh92x4HrjPL2tQ"/>,
 'title': 'Duitsland lanceert <b>corona</b>-tracing-<b>app</b>'}
```

However, the output I am looking for is:

```
{'link': 'https://duitslandinstituut.nl/artikel/38250/duitsland-lanceert-corona-tracing-app&amp;ct=ga&amp;cd=CAIyGWFlODkwMWNhMWM0YmE4ODU6bmw6bmw6Tkw&amp;usg=AFQjCNHDFPconO3h8mpzJh92x4HrjPL2tQ',
 'published': '2020-06-11T15:33:11Z',
 'source': 'Duitslandinstituut'
 'title': 'Duitsland lanceert corona-tracing-app'}
```

So, firstly, I want to lose the google link part. Secondly, I would like the source to be the name coming after the second 'https://', with a capital letter.  Third, I want to remove any <\b> etc attributes from the title. I am planning to put the results into a bibliography, so the text can't contain any computer code.

I tried to fix this in BS4 but could not. Someone advised my to do it in pandas df afterwards with regex, but I am not familiar with regex and it is hard to understand for examples. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `for` loop along these lines:

```
for item in items:
      news_item = {}
      news_item['link'] = item.link['href']
      news_item['published'] = item.published.text
      source = item.link['href'].split('//')[2].split('.')[1].capitalize()
      news_item['source'] = source
      news_items.append(news_item)
      n_s = BeautifulSoup(item.title.text,'lxml')
      new_t = ''.join(n_s.find_all(text=True))
      news_item['title'] = new_t
for item in news_items:
    print(item)
```

Output (at the time I ran it):

```
{'link': 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2020/06/12/de-nieuwe-corona-app-een-balanceeract-tussen-te-streng-en-te-soft-a4002678&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGWFlODkwMWNhMWM0YmE4ODU6bmw6bmw6Tkw&usg=AFQjCNFc54u6UszfKuIsSWFHQ_JTeqfIQA', 'published': '2020-06-12T14:37:30Z', 'source': 'Nrc', 'title': "De nieuwe corona-app: een balanceeract tussen 'te streng' en 'te soft'"}
{'link': 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.standaard.be/cnt/dmf20200612_04989287&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGWFlODkwMWNhMWM0YmE4ODU6bmw6bmw6Tkw&usg=AFQjCNHtIbdXB6q3hcvnNTvG7KC76fV7xQ', 'published': '2020-06-12T11:46:32Z', 'source': 'Standaard', 'title': 'Mobiele coronateams en app tegen tweede golf'}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.replace` method on a string if you don't want to use regex. And `urllib.parse.urlparse` to get the domain from a url.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse 

def parse(url):
    news_items = []
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

    items = soup.find_all('entry')

    for item in items:
        title = item.title.text.replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '')
        link = item.link['href'].replace(
            'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=', '').split('&')[0]
        source = urlparse(link).netloc.split('.')[1].title()
        published = item.published.text

        news_items.append(dict(zip(
            ['link', 'published', 'source', 'title'], [link, published, source, title]
        )))
    return news_items
```